# Украинский язык в djangoCMS

Tags: django, локализация, django-cms

Доброго времени суток, не могу понять как подключить украинский язык в djangoCMS.
Django 1.8.7
DjangoCMS 3.4.2
Python 3.5

```
LANGUAGE_CODE = 'ru'

LANGUAGES = [
    ('ru', 'Russian'),
    ('ua', 'Ukrainian'),
    ('en', 'English')
]
```

В меню отсвечивают все 3 языка. Если переключиться на Английский например то все ок, а если на Украинский выдает 404 причем с адресом */ru/ua/ например. Пытался выставить его в LANGUAGE-CODE получаю ошибку что такого нет `OSError: No translation files found for default language ua.` Кто сталкивался может быть, подскажите что делать?

Using the URLconf defined in main.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:

```
^media/(?P<path>.*)$
^static\/(?P<path>.*)$
^sitemap\.xml$
^ru/ ^admin/
^ru/ ^ ^cms_wizard/
^ru/ ^ ^(?P<slug>[0-9A-Za-z-_.//]+)/$ [name='pages-details-by-slug']
^ru/ ^ ^$ [name='pages-root']

The current URL, /ru/ua/, didn't match any of these.
```

Получаю такую ошибку если пытаюсь переключиться на украинскую версию.

Comment: Django CMS не поддерживает украинский.

Comment: Может есть возможность локализацию достать и установить откуда нибудь?

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev вроде поддерживает. https://www.transifex.com/divio/django-cms/

Comment: @NickitaDavidenko похоже, что вот тут нужная вам документация. http://docs.django-cms.org/en/release-3.4.x/topics/i18n.html

Comment: @NickVolynkin этого языка нет в [репотизитории на githab'е](https://github.com/divio/django-cms/tree/release/3.4.x/cms/locale) и он не входит в [пакет, распространяемый через PyPI](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-cms/3.4.2). Так что из коробки не поддерживает. Но доустановить из стороннего источника можно.

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev Наверное, они не включают все 92 языка в коробочную версию. Но раз на Transifex есть на 100% завершенный перевод, то он точно где-нибудь доступен. ))

Comment: Да я находил на transifex, потому и спрашиваю можно ли самому добавить его?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Все что мне надо было сделал с помощью CMS_LANGUAGES

```
CMS_LANGUAGES = {
## Customize this
'default': {
    'public': True,
    'hide_untranslated': False,
    'redirect_on_fallback': True,
},
1: [
    {
        'name': 'Русский',
        'public': True,
        'hide_untranslated': False,
        'redirect_on_fallback': True,
        'code': 'ru',
    },
    {
        'name': 'Українська',
        'public': True,
        'hide_untranslated': False,
        'redirect_on_fallback': True,
        'code': 'uk',
    },
    {
        'name': 'English',
        'public': True,
        'hide_untranslated': False,
        'redirect_on_fallback': True,
        'code': 'en',
    },
],
}
```

И все заработало. Теперь есть возможность создавать страницы под нужными языками.